# Move secrets and credentials out of code in Kubeflow pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, credentials, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am using Kubeflow pipelines to run some ML workflow. Now I have a python code which sets the Environment variable in the container and uses it. Currently I have stored it as a string in code directly under @func_to_container_op annotated function. What I want to do is move it out of the code. Here is a snippet of the code I am using currently.

```
secret_file_json_obj = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "abcd",
    "private_key_id": "abcd",
    "private_key": """abcd""",
    "client_email": "abcd",
    "client_id": "abcd",
}

secret_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'abcd.json')
with open(secret_file_path, 'w') as secret_file_json:
    secret_file_json.write(json.dumps(secret_file_json_obj, ensure_ascii=False))
secret_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), secret_file_path)

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = secret_file
```

The use case is that the credentials can change and code shouldn't be changed for changing just the credentials.

Comment: What part of the code do you want to move out of pipeline? `secret_file_json_obj` or `secret_file_path` or something else?

Comment: Basically `secret_file_json_obj` which is just a json representation of a google service account key.

Comment: You need to use (Kubernetes best practice to manage secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)